# How do I know which delimiter was used when delimiting a string on multiple delimiters? (C#)

Tags: c#, string, split, delimiter

I read strings from a file and they come in various styles:

```
item0 item1 item2 
item0,item1,item2
item0_item1_item2
```

I split them like this:

```
string[] split_line = line[i].split(new char[] {' ',',','_'});
```

I change an item (column) and then i stitch the strings back together using string builder. 
But now when putting the string back I have to use the right delimiter.

Is it possible to know which delimiter was used when splitting the string?

***UPDATE***
the caller will pass me the first item so that I only change that line.

Comment: This would be really annoying. Not to figure out how to **do** it, but to figure out how to store it. If they come in separate lines you could make a FileLine class with a `char` delimiter field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you keep track of splitting action (one at the time) you don't.
Otherwise, you could create a regular expression, to catch the item and the delimiter and go from there.

Comment: `you could create a regular expression, to catch the item and the delimiter and go from there.` I think the question is **how**?

Comment: @Saamorim, if I know what the delim is it would be quite easy!

Comment: How about finding some character that doesn't appear in the string (e.g. `☃`), replacing every delimiter with a two-character sequence starting with that character, and splitting based upon that?  Not necessarily the most performant approach, but it should work.

Comment: @infinitloop, yes you do know what they are! You've mentioned them : `{' ',',','_'}` Just don't process them in batch. A possible regular expression could be: `(?<itemvalue>[^ ,_]+)(?<separator>[ ,_]?)`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing in an array of characters, you can use a Regex to split the string instead. The advantage of doing this, is that you can capture the splitting character. Regex.Split will insert any captures between elements in the array like so:

```
string[] space = Regex.Split("123 456 789", @"([,_ ])");
// Results in { "123", " ", "456", " ", "789" }
string[] comma = Regex.Split("123,456,789", @"([,_ ])");
// Results in { "123", ",", "456", ",", "789" }
string[] underscore = Regex.Split("123_456_789", @"([,_ ])");
// Results in { "123", "_", "456", "_", "789" }
```

Then you can edit all items in the array with something like

```
for (int x = 0; x < space.Length; x += 2)
    space[x] = space[x] + "x";
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", space));
// Will print: 123x 456x 789x
```

One thing to be wary of when dealing with multiple separators is if there are any lines that have spaces, commas and underscores in them. e.g.

```
 37,hello world,238_3
```

This code will preserve all the distinct separators but your results might not be expected. e.g. the output of the above would be:

```
 37x,hellox worldx,238x_3x
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned that the caller passes me the first item so I tried something like this:

```
// find the right row
if (lines[i].ToLower().StartsWith(rowID))
{
  // we have to know which delim was used to split the string since this will be 
  // used when stitching back the string together.
  for (int delim = 0; delim < delims.Length; delim++)
  {
   // we split the line into an array and then use the array index as our column index
   split_line = lines[i].Trim().Split(delims[delim]);
   // we found the right delim
   if (split_line.Length > 1)
   {
     delim_used = delims[delim];
     break;
   }
  }
}
```

basically I iterate each line over the delims and check the resulting array length. If it is > 1 that means that delim worked otherwise skip to next one. I am using split functions property "`If this instance does not contain any of the characters in separator, the returned array consists of a single element that contains this instance.`"